Why is the expected value of their total bankroll is $i$?
Imagine a gambler has USD $1$ to bet on a sequence of $n$ heads $(HHHH\cdots H)_n$ in a fair game with the following rule:
Bets are placed on up to $n$ consecutive games (tosses), and each time the gambler bets all his money (unless he goes bankrupt). For example, if H appears at the first game, he will have USD $2$, and he will put all USD $2$ into the second game. He stops playing either when he loses a game or when he wins $n$ games in a roll, in which case he collects $2^n$ (with probability $1/2^n$). Now let’s imagine, instead of one gambler, before each toss, a new gambler joins the game and bets on the same sequence of $n$ heads with a bankroll of USD 1 as well. After the $i$-th game, $i$ gamblers have participated in the game, and the total amount of money they have put in the game should be USD $i$. Since each game is fair, the expected value of their total bankroll is $i$ as well.
I am stuck here. Why is the expected value of their total bankroll is $i$?
Is it just $E[X] = \sum_{j=1}^i g_j \times p_j= \sum_{j=1}^i 1 \times 1 = i$, where $g_j$ is $j$th gambler's contribution and with probability $p_j =1$?

Not sure I am following.  You provide a perfectly clear argument for saying the expected value is $1$ (or $i$ if there are $i$ players):  Each game, individually, is expected to yield $0$.  What else are you asking?

The expectation definition is $E[x] = \sum x p(x)$. How do we calculate expectations from here in the gambling case? I was doing a long calculation so I might get lost in a simple argument. Is the justification below correct? Otherwise, You can write your justification for why the expectation is $i$ for $i$ players.
$E[X] = \sum_{j=1}^i g_j \times p_j= \sum_{j=1}^i 1 \times 1 = i$, where $g_j$ is $j$th gambler's contribution and with probability $p_j =1$

But of course it is hard to write it out that way, because figuring out the probability that the group wins exactly $x$ is messy.  No need to do any of that, though, as expectation is linear so the answer is just $i$ times the expectation for a single player, which you already know to be $1$
